# Coldfusion cookie issue

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, add-on

I'm having issues deleting client cookies with the cfcookie tag, I'm setting the value to "" AND changing the expiration date to now.

But I think it's resetting the cookie in the same page that it deletes it.

Is there a application (or addon for chrome,firefox) that can tell me where it's giving me cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), an application that logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet.

1) Run Fiddler.
2) Open your site on the browser you use.
3) Look at the request and response headers on Fiddler. Any cookie set or delete will be there.

Other references:
[Fiddler Can Make Debugging Easy](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/article.php/3631066/Fiddler-Can-Make-Debugging-Easy.htm). [September 12, 2006]
[Fiddler Proxy and HTTP Debugging Tool](http://www.globinch.com/2010/12/17/fiddler-proxy-and-http-debugging-tool/) [December 17, 2010]

Answer (score 1):

As tiangoinu said, use Fiddler for Windows, or if you're on a mac, check out [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

As to your specific question, verify that you're not doing a redirect after you delete the cookie. In order for the cookie to be deleted on the client, the necessary HTTP headers need to be passed to the browser, and sometimes a cflocation will prevent those headers from being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at HTTPLive Headers for FireFox. Or some other type of intercept proxy to put between the browser and the server.  You can then see the HTTP headers and try to determine where the cookies are being set (or at least how often).